# How do to determine if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left((n+1)^{1/3}-(n-1)^{1/3}\right)^a$ is convergent

Tags: limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Series converge or diverge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12052/series-converge-or-diverge)

I have failed to determine if the following series converges or diverges, I tried using d’Alembert's ratio test and found that the limit of the ratio of two consecutive values in the general element of the series is $1$. I need to be able to tell for what values of $a$ ($a$ is real) the series converges and diverges.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left((n+1)^{1/3}-(n-1)^{1/3}\right)^a$$

Thanks!

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$.

Comment: What you wrote was unambiguous, but $\LaTeX$ does make the mathematics easier to read; for future reference you can find $\LaTeX$ help [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).